# Setting a correct statement for various calculations from an array

Tags: arrays, if-statement, numpy, while-loop

I have an array

```
 a = np.array([1.5, 0.55, 3.0, 0.24])
```

I want to create a statement that would create a new array such that a[i] > 1 then b = 1.0*a and that everything is has b = 2.0*a. I am not sure if this would be better for an if or a while statement. I am just trying to get my b array to be this:

```
b = [1.5, 1.10, 3.0, 0.48])
```

Comment: what do you mean by `everything is has b = 2.0*a.`?

Comment: if  a[i] <1 then b = 2.0*a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
b = a + (a <= 1) * a
```

Or you could use `numpy.where`:

```
b = numpy.where(a > 1, a, 2 * a)
```

Comment: Yes this numpy.where statement works well for me since I could change the conditions for other numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a = np.array([1.5, 0.55, 3.0, 0.24])
a[ a <= 1] *= 2
print a
```